# Shutdown takes longer with proxy and VPN

Tags: shutdown, vpn, proxy

Some times ago I started to using VPN with dedicated proxy. I observed that shooting down ubuntu takes much longer when I don't turn the proxy off before turning PC off.

Do you know what ubuntu is using internet connection while stout down?